# pandas dataframe count should be int64

Tags: pandas

How to make the type below int64?

```
m1 = df.groupby('Time')['Bid'].agg(o='first', h='max', l='min', c='last', v='count')
print(m1['v'].dtype)

float64
```

Comment: `m1['v']=m1['v'].astype('int64')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:
`m1['v_int'] = m1['v'].astype(int)`
If there is any decimal number it will be rounded to the nearest integer